# Get localized list/site name from SharePoint 2013 on-premise with CSOM

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have multilingual sites on my SharePoint 2013 server (on-premise) and I would like to retrieve localized sites and lists name via the .NET Managed API (CSOM) in C#.

I tried to use the ["TitleResource" property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.titleresource.aspx) object from Web object and its [GetValueForUICulture()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userresource.getvalueforuiculture.aspx) method :

```
var web = spContext.Web;
var webTitleRes = web.TitleResource;
var webFrenchTitle = webTitleRes.GetValueForUICulture("fr").Value;
spContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But it crashes at the last line saying that this field/property doesn't exist:

[image: Fig. 1]

I previously tried to update the Web's "LocaleID" value as it is showed in a sample app from the Office PnP project : [check here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.Settings.LocaleAndLanguage)

But the server throw an Exception, saying that I don't have enough permission to do that :

[image: Fig. 2]

Well, I don't really want to update the LocaleID on the server, I just want to locally retrieve localized titles so it seems to be a completely wrong way.

How can I retrieve localized title's string from my SharePoint server? What am I missing?

---

## Update

For reference, it seems that *TitleResource* and *DescriptionResource* attributes are only accessible from the "online" version of SharePoint, yet the MSDN doc doesn't mention anything about that, leading to a improper use of these :

[image: Fig. 3]

It may be usable in the brand new 2016 version, btw. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

the UiCulture should be a Culture object.

Try this:

```
blablabla.GetValueForUICulture(new CultureInfo(1036)).Value;
```

Comment: Hmm, but the doc say that it has to be a string (I'm using the Client Object Model): [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userresource.getvalueforuiculture.aspx). Btw, Visual Studio reject this line. And it still say that "TitleResource" does not exist. Although the doc write that this is for SharePoint 2013, I'm not sure if it's true or an Microsoft's error.

Comment: if i remember well, this is online for SharePoint online (O365). On premise SP's are limited in multilanguage through CSOM. Only option: serverside-code. To use remote: deploy a webservice that calls serverside code and call it from a remote machine

Comment: That effectively seems to be the case, sadly. The MSDN doc page isn't really clear as it says that it is accessible from "SharePoint 2013" (with no mention that it is exclusively accessible from the online version). Thanks for your help anyway! :)